# HTML calling Perl Perl Calling Script Script SSH not working

Tags: html, linux, bash, perl

I'm able to pass a variable from HTML form to a simple perl script.  This is the main line from perl script.

```
 system("/var/www/cgi-bin/aaa $name")
```

The perl script calls a bash  script called aaa.
As you see I pass the $name which is the  entry from my html form  to aaa bash script.
In my bash script  I can echo the $name as $1 or assign $1 to $name. 
So so far so good. That's the way I want it. However in my aaa bash script 
I have a ssh command in aaa script that is not working. No matter how many different way 
I tried it it just not working. If I run the aaa script command from command line and pass a parameter , the script works fine, but when I try it via the perl it fails.

my ssh command right now is very simple. So my aaa bash file contains a simple line

```
 echo $1      
 ssh $1 "ls -altr" > /var/www/cgi-bin/output
```

If I call this script from command line ( aaa serverx )  It works fine.
Now I do it through the html form and the only thing that works is the echo $1 command.
Another word I can see that I'm passing the right servername  ( example serverx) and when I do echo $1 I can see the serverx. However, the ssh line fails. Noyt sure what to do ? Can anyone help ?

Regards

Comment: Did you just stutter online?

Comment: Are you running the PHP script from the webserver? It won't use your SSH username or private key.

Comment: @matthewthegreat You might want to quote your variables (although it probably won't solve the problem it should add *some* protection).

Comment: Barmer - I'm running the bash script  from the webserver. The bash as I mentioned works fine from command line.   Biffen, I tried the quote. I tried various options. Just not sure why ssh is failing withing the script.

Comment: thank you all appreciated. I'm trying to find how I can do the ssh directly from perl without passing the param to another bash file.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890239/running-bash-command-using-ssh-in-perl

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should do things within Perl script there should be no need for aaa script, There might be many reasons why ssh is not working, it could be simply because you closed STDIN , STDOUT at the higher level or have redirection enabled ?  That might simply explain why it works from command line but not from another wrapper..  Have you tried to run ssh inside the perl script and see if that works?  Is it possible to share some parts of code snippet?

Comment: Hi Thanks. I re-stated my question following yoru advice. Hopefully someone will reply
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890239/running-bash-command-using-ssh-in-perl